# get data from listwidget in QT creator C++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlistwidget, collect

in my program, customers added items in cart. I displayed all items in cart in a list Widget. If customer wants to remove anything, they can do it, else, they can proceed.

I am trying to assign the data inside that list Widget to a vector when customer press the "next" button, but I couldn't figure out which code to type.

I tried
'''ui->listWdiget->takeItem(i);'''

in a for loop, but my program crashed.

I am new to the QT creator, so I don't know many of the key words.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Use the debugger to find out on which line the program crashes... And show us your code. Without seeing the code we cannot know what the problem is.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile I found the solution. https://forum.qt.io/topic/115875/how-d-i-load-a-textfile-to-qlistwidget-and-also-save-it-back/2 

I was not using QWidgetList as this person did. I typed "save listWidget" and i found the solution. I was typing "get data" all this time. But thank you